# connect to a remote Windows Server using Java and change the directory in remote,place specific files and execute some commands in command prompt

Tags: java, windows, psexec

Need help on this.

I have a requirement where I need to automate the below flow.

Connect to a remote server from local,change the directory and copy a specific file to a specific folder from local to remote,executing some commands in command prompt,coming back to local and checking in SQL Server.

Local and remote both are windows operating systems

Tried using psexec as shown in below code , getting error on changing the directory ?

public class Test2 {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("cmd");
    list.add("/c")  ;
    list.add("start psexec \\\\ip_address -u dev\\username -p password cmd");
    list.add("cd c:\\Operations\\Account Updater"); //changing the directory
    ProcessBuilder builder =new ProcessBuilder(list);
   Process p= builder.start();

   String s; 
   System.out.println(p.getOutputStream()); 
   BufferedReader stdInput =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   while((s=stdInput.readLine())!=null){ 
       System.out.println(s); 
       }

   System.out.println(builder.command());


}
```

}

Also how to copy files from local to Remote using Java code ?

Manually I am able to perform all the operations using psexec.

Please let me know if there are any other ways apart from using psexec for automating this flow.

Comment: look up jsch http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ you can connect to remote machines via ssh & sftp

Comment: @Joe Can you please give more insights on Jsch and how it works.If possible how to connect to a remote Windows Server using JSch ?  As I see Jsch is for connecting ssh servers, I am not sure whether my remote server is ssh or not.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Look at source examples of Jsch, thats how I did it. Just install an SSH server on your windows server and you should be able to connect